# map over an array to find the sum of elements in sub arrays belonging to differents objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

hope the title was not cryptic enough :) .  I'm trying to explain the question better: I have this array with the following data (example)

```
const data = [
{
  name: "Bob",
  items: [1]
},
{
name: "charlie",
items: [1,2]
},
{
name: "Chris",
items: [5]
}

]
```

I've put the items in an array because sometimes can be more than one. Now my question is: how can I find the sum of those items so it would be 4? (first array has one element, second has two, and the last one 1)  I don't know why I'm having such a big time with this guys... I've tried to map the item property and then use a reduce function, but it gaves me back one single array...
Thanks guys for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce` to calculate the sum of the lengths of `items` lists:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Bob", items: [1] },
  { name: "charlie", items: [1,2] },
  { name: "Chris", items: [5] }
];

const sum = data.reduce((total, { items = [] }) => total + items.length, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Sorry, I formulated wrong my question : how can I find the sum of those items so it would be 4? (first array has one element, second has two, and the last one 1). So I would like not the sum of the numbers, but the actual elements inside (and I can't use an es2019 compiler so no flatMap if possible.)

Comment: @ChirstianaEriksten I updated the answer, according to what I understood from the question, you want to get the sum of the number of elements in the items lists

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data .length; i++) {
  var object = arrayOfObjects[i];
  sum += object.items.length;
}
```

Iterate over the objects in the JSON array in the for loop and add the sums of the items arrays

Comment: Sorry, I formulated wrong my question : how can I find the sum of those items so it would be 4? (first array has one element, second has two, and the last one 1). So I would like not the sum of the numbers, but the actual elements inside

Comment: @ChirstianaEriksten I've edited my answer, just sum up all the lengths of the items, if that what you ment

Answer (score 1):

```
data.filter(ele => {
  var summ = ele.items.reduce((sum, current) => sum + current, 0);
  if(summ === 9) return ele
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I formulated wrong my question : how can I find the sum of those items so it would be 4? (first array has one element, second has two, and the last one 1). So I would like not the sum of the numbers, but the actual elements inside